# How to add selected players from MyPlayerActivity and add those players into MainActivity Map as markers?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mapbox

I would like to select few players ( highlighted in purple colors ie Player 1, Player 3 & Player 5) from 'MyPlayerActivity' and add these selected players into a mapbox Map as markers (MainActivity) during on click on 'Add Player' button.
Could someone please help me on how to achieve this ?

[image]

Following is my 'MyPlayerActivity' code

```
public class MyPlayerActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static int lastClickId = -1;

    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] players = new String[] {
            "Player 1",
            "Player 2",
            "Player 3",
            "Player 4",
            "Player 5"            
    };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] images = new int[]{
            R.drawable.play_1,
            R.drawable.play_2,
            R.drawable.play_3,
            R.drawable.play_4,
            R.drawable.play_5

    };



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        View headerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
        getListView().addHeaderView(headerView);


        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("label", "" + players[i]);
            hm.put("imgs", Integer.toString(images[i]) );
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "imgs","label"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.imgs,R.id.label};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.list_view, from, to);


        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file


        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Item Click Listener for the listview
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container, int position, long id) {

                // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
                RelativeLayout relativeLayoutParent = (RelativeLayout) container;

                //LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) container;

                RelativeLayout relativeLayoutChild = (RelativeLayout) relativeLayoutParent.getChildAt(1);

                // Getting the inner Linear Layout
               // LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = (LinearLayout ) linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(1);

                // Getting the Player TextView
                TextView myPlayer = (TextView) relativeLayoutChild.getChildAt(0);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), myPlayer.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        };

        // Setting the item click listener for the listview
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }



}

Following is the list_view.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgs"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="17sp" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Add_Player"
        android:background="#66ccff"
        android:textColor="#ffffff">
    </Button>


    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>

Below is the 'MainActivity' code, where I have initialized my map and this is where I would need to add my Player markers and display in mapbox map.


'MainActivity' code where I have initialized my map: 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap map;   
    private Marker customMarker;   
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MapboxAccountManager.start(this, "token");
        final boolean permissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();
        onMapReady(map);
        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

                Log.i("MapAsync", " is called");
                //you need to initialize 'map' with 'mapboxMap';
                map = mapboxMap;
                //map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new LatLng);

                map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new MapboxMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
                        if (customMarker != null) {
                            // Remove previous added marker
                            map.removeAnnotation(customMarker);
                            customMarker = null;
                        }
                        customMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .title("Custom Marker")
                                .snippet(new DecimalFormat("#.#####").format(point.getLatitude()) + ", "
                                        + new DecimalFormat("#.#####").format(point.getLongitude()))
                                .position(point));

                    }
                }); // Long click Ends here


            }

        });      




    } 




// Initialize the onMapReady
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        this.map = mapboxMap;


    }



    private void addDrawerItems() {
        String[] osArray = { "Map", "Players", "Video", "TestPlayer", "My Profile"};
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // depending on the position in your drawer list change this
                switch (position) {
                    case 0: {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Access map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    }
                    case 1:{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListPlayerActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "See players arena", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }

                    case 2:{

                        Intent appIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayYoutubeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(appIntent);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "See Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }

                    case 3:{

                        Intent appIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyPlayerActivity.class);
                        startActivity(appIntent);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test to see my players", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }

                    default:
                        break;

                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "More details to follow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    // Add the mapView lifecycle to the activity's lifecycle methods
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    public class TelemetryServiceNotConfiguredException extends RuntimeException {

        public TelemetryServiceNotConfiguredException() {
            super("\nTelemetryService is not configured in your applications AndroidManifest.xml. " +
                    "\nPlease add \"com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.TelemetryService\" service in your applications AndroidManifest.xml" +
                    "\nFor an example visit For more information visit https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/.");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a marker to the map you can use this snippet:

```
mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerViewOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(<position of player>)));
```

If the listview and map are in separate activities, you can pass the selected player information to the map activity using an intent. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: How can we get selected player names  from the List view and pass in an Intent

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(MyPlayerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",id);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });